# VueJs dynamic buttons value

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So I'm looping through my `allItems` Array of Objects and I want to show something when a certain button is clicked.

**allItems**

```
allItems = [
   {
       title: 'test',
       show: false,
       description: 'this is test'
   },
   {
       title: 'test 1',
       show: false,
       description: 'the test 1'
   }
]
```

**List.vue**

```
v-col cols="3" v-for="item in allItems" :key="item.id">
      <v-card width="100%">

        <v-card-text>
          <span class="text--primary">
            <span class="title">{{ item.title.substring(0,28)+".." }}</span>
          </span>
        </v-card-text>

        <v-card-actions>
          <v-btn icon @click="item.show = !item.show">
            <v-icon>{{ item.show ? 'mdi-menu-up' : 'mdi-menu-down' }}</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
        <v-expand-transition>
          <div v-if="item.show">
            <span class="pt-10">{{ item.description }}</span>
          </div>
        </v-expand-transition>
      </v-card>
 </v-col>
```

My problem is when the button is getting clicked its not opening the description.

**EDIT**

It looks like I didn't put much info. I'm using `Vuex` to handle my state.

**PS:** I'm not passing the computed value anymore to the child component.

in my **List.vue** script

```
import { mapActions, mapGetters } from "vuex";

export default {
data: () => ({}),
methods: {
  ...mapActions(["fetchItems"])
},
created() {
  this.fetchItems();
},
computed: mapGetters(["allItems"])
};
```

Comment: The code you posted is working fine when i reproduced. Where did you define `allItems` ? Is is inside component's data method?

Comment: @NafeesAnwar from`props: ['allItems']`

Comment: @Priz I'd suggest checking where you are setting the props, as this code works perfect: https://codepen.io/Tiarhai/pen/QWLpzvQ

Comment: You must add to element v:bind attr .   https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html

Answer (score 2):

From your reply to the comments, I see you are passing your data as a prop and want it to be reactive. **In Vue, all props form a one-way-down binding between the child property and the parent one.**

So to reactively change the prop value, you can:

1. Set a data value which you will assign the props value to so that you can reactively change the state data instead.
2. You can aslo define a computed value from the prop and use the computed value instead

Read more on the [vue docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow)

Answer (score 0):

As Onwuka wrote, don't modify the props directly in the child. I think what would make a lot of sense here is if you removed the `show` prop entirely from the items. Then you create a custom component e.g. `ListItem.vue` that contains your entire element and takes the `item` as a prop. Then each of these smaller components can keep track of its own  state (visible/hidden) in the components `data`.

Comment: The same remains true for vuex state. If you want to modify the state, you would need to commit these changes to the store by using `this.$store.commit()` to commit a mutation. Don't directly modify the state in your component.